# How to get updated model information in MVC without reloading view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating an MVC app.  The user selects a category from a select list (which is populated by one model, companies).  In response, a second select list needs to be updated based on the value selected in the first list (from an different model, applications).

'applications' is too large to load all of the data every time the view is loaded, so it has to be filtered.

I've tried recalling the view with the selected value in 'companies' as a parameter which works just fine to get the proper data from 'applications', but I need a javascript script to run on page reload and the browser won't rerun scripts on reload (or even different scripts).

How can I request the filtered data without reloading the page, OR how can I force the browser to run a script on page reload?  Thanks

note: I've tried suggestions I found indicating that removing the script block (or the innerHTML) and rewriting it will fix the script-not-running issue, but none of those suggestions worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery AJAX should help you here. Say your select is `#target` so do:

```
$('#target').change(function () {
    $.getJSON(url, { id: $(this).prop('selectedIndex') })
        .done(function () { ... });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I've updated this with a partial view that contains the second select box.  How would I use your code to call/refresh just the partial view?

Comment: This led me to an ajax solution that worked, thanks!